# Flutter Rest api call don't working on android

Tags: android, flutter, rest, dart

**my flutter application does not send requests to my server in the real android emulator or simulator I don't think there is a problem on the server side because it works normally on ios in the same way I can send requests with postman I tried the ways I saw on the internet but it didn't get better my android manifest file is like this thanks for your help in advance**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="seederzone"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you provide minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough, iOS doesn't require that but [Android](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-app-manifest) does.

Make sure after you save the updated AndroidManifest.xml you perform a full reinstall on your device, by running these at your project folder:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run --release
```

ps:
You can also try this simple code to check if it really is a internet permission problem or if it is your requisition (add the http package and run on release mode):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _displayText = '';

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    final url = 'https://dummyjson.com/carts';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String result = response.body;
        setState(() {
          _displayText = result.substring(0, 100);
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _displayText = 'Failed to load data from the URL.';
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _displayText = 'Error: ${e.toString()}';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              _displayText,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _fetchData,
              child: Text('Fetch Data'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ı tried but doesnt work

Comment: are you running a real device or the emulator? what is the error message log that you get when the request fails?

Comment: It does not send requests to my server in the emulator or on the real device, so I cannot get an error, even if it is not in release mode, that is, when I say flutter run in my android emulator in a normal way, when I run and try it, it does not send requests to my server, but it works smoothly on ios, I have ssl on my website where I send requests, could it be a situation caused by this?

Comment: if your problem is internet permission you SHOULD be getting a SocketException. Post your code with the requisition, so that we can try to help, otherwise it is pure speculation.

Comment: it was not giving any exception I solved my problem anyway thank you for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem, maybe there will be those who experience the same error, I am writing the solution here, since my website, which I send requests with api, uses ssl, this cannot be verified on the android side and did not send requests to the server. To fix this, I added my ssl certificate to my assets and added the following to the main file of my application
**

```
  final ByteData data =
      await PlatformAssetBundle().load('assets/cert/my_cert.pem');
  SecurityContext.defaultContext
      .setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
```

**The codes you need to add are as I mentioned above**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final ByteData data =
      await PlatformAssetBundle().load('assets/cert/my_cert.pem');
  SecurityContext.defaultContext
      .setTrustedCertificatesBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  final appDocumentDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDir.path);
  await Hive.openBox<String>("AppDatabase");
  await initializeDateFormatting('tr_TR').then((_) {
    runApp(
      EasyLocalization(
        supportedLocales: AppConstants.SUPPORTED_LOCALES,
        path: AppConstants.LANG_PATH,
        child: const MyApp(),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```